# How to build a wallet in my computer?

Tags: client, wallet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What software and skills do I need?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/what-software-and-skills-do-i-need)

I have seen on the wiki, there are too many steps (hard steps for a non-geek person) to build a wallet. Is there a easy way for a new non-geek bitcoin user? (some kind of script?). Thanks.

EDIT: I want to build my first wallet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question, as it is not really clear on what you want to accomplish. Are you trying to create your first wallet to be used with the standard client, a wallet with new keys, or build a wallet in a different programming language, data structure or the like?

Comment: @H_7 , Please link the Wiki article that you referring to. Bitcoin client creates wallet automatically if it doesn't find one in designated directory.

Comment: @H_7, There is no "building" required.  Install the client it will make a wallet by default.  Done.

Comment: Seems like the question is simply about getting started with Bitcoin. This question will answer that for you: [What software and skills do I need?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/what-software-and-skills-do-i-need). Should we even close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: I would tend to agree with D.H. - this question only sounds like it's not a dupe because the user wasn't familiar enough with Bitcoin to phrase it in a way that makes it more obvious. Closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your first wallet, just install the Bitcoin client and run it.

If you want to have a new wallet, backup your old wallet.dat and run the Bitcoin client again.

If you want to build a custom wallet with tailored structure and so forth, I don't think you're a non-geek user.

Comment: _just install the Bitcoin client and run it._  It's that really simple like it sounds?

Comment: @H_7.  Yes it is that simple.  Download here http://bitcoin.org install like any other app and then launch the Bitcoin wallet.  I recommend you enable encryption.

Comment: @H_7: Yes, the basic client does pretty much everything you need to start using Bitcoins right out of the box. Note: it can take awhile to download the whole blockchain (you`ll see the number next to blocks on the bottom increasing up to about 151000).