# Can anyone without knowledge of encrypted tech use bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am interested in registering online, however I haven't got any knowledge on encrypted language not even on software design or whatever it is called.  Is it possible for a person like me to register and enjoy the benefits from bitcoin that surely will become the currency of our modern generation:)

Comment: related: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/5406), possible duplicate of [What software and skills do I need?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1635/5406)

Comment: People know nothing about fiat currency, and the tech behind it, but they use it all the time.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use Bitcoin, it is no harder than using a credit card or online-banking. I suggest reading up on some safety best-practices in order to protect your funds, and to use two-factor authentication.

We have put together a collection of frequent questions new users ask. It is to be found here: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/5406).
It is essentially a bunch of pointers to yet other questions, but should help you find answers to questions that you are concerned with now. Don't worry, you don't have to read all of them at one time or even at all.

If you want to understand how Bitcoin works under the hood, it is more complicated. However, when you think about it, so are credit cards and online-banking. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use the bitcoin without knowledge of encrypted tech !
all you have to do is to create an online wallet and after everything its easy.
Mining its another story , you will need very strong hardware in order to create bitcoins by yourself.
You can start things going from here : https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet .

Regards